# this.appRef.attachView is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material-8

Im using **@angular/core** and **@angular/common** version **8.2.14**; and **@angular/cdk** and **@angular/material** **8.2.3**.

When i try using Angular material's mat-dialog i get this error:

**TypeError: this.appRef.attachView is not a function.**

The same error i get for Angular material's snackbar and bottom sheet as well.

I have searched a lot online about this error, and found that its because of version mismatch between angular and angular/cdk but it does'nt seem to be in my case. Any help/lead on this?

Comment: I'm also started seeing the same issue, did you find any solution to this? I'm wondering what could have caused this error. In my case its ionic and angular, opening modal, toaster, alert, etc causing an issue.